# Составление маски для $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить маску, чтобы при помощи $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] определить страницы вида:

```
1) site.com/catalog/_любое_сочетание_символов_  
2) site.com/catalog/category/_любое_сочетание_символов_  
3) site.com/catalog/_любое_сочетание_символов_.html
```

где `_любое_сочетание_символов_` это латиница, цифры, дефисы, подчёркивания и слэши

Спасибо!

Comment: вы о регулярных выражениях? если да, то приведите примеры, какие вы уже пробовали, и что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(site.com/catalog/(.*))$
```

регулярное выражение( в Вашем случае достаточно одного), но на всякий случай уточняющие РВ:

1. ^(site.com/catalog/category/(.*))$
2. ^(site.com/catalog/(.*).html)$

   - ^ - начало строки
   - (.*) - любое сочетание символов
   - $ - конец строки